# Is it possible to only trigger a media query if a certain variable is a certain value?

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

I am trying to remove an element from my window if the screen size is below a 1000px and variable is greater than 15.

I have my css file:

```
@media (max-width: 1000px){
  #specific-id{
     display:none
   }
}
```

but I only want this to occur if the variable is greater than 15. How can I implement javascript control to this?

Comment: You could have javascript conditionally add/remove a class to the element based on that criteria

Comment: what is the underlying problem you are trying to solve? as @Nick pointed out you can just toggle classes on the html element based on your variables value

Comment: I have a variable that changes the size of a container based on the variable's number. So when the variable is too high and the screen size is too low, I want to remove the container from the screen. 
edit: increasing the variable value increases the container size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way for this is to add a class that is only added if variable is bigger than 15:

if variable is less than 15:

```js
const variable = 0
const specificId = document.getElementById('specific-id')

if (variable > 15) {
  specificId.classList.add("variableIsMoreThan15")
}
```

```css
#specific-id {
  background: red;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px){
  .variableIsMoreThan15 {
     display:none
   }
}
```

```html
<div id="specific-id">
Hello
</div>
```

if variable is greater than 15:

```js
const variable = 16
const specificId = document.getElementById('specific-id')

if (variable > 15) {
  specificId.classList.add("variableIsMoreThan15")
}
```

```css
#specific-id {
  background: red;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px){
  .variableIsMoreThan15 {
     display:none
   }
}
```

```html
<div id="specific-id">
Hello
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a custom media query you can try

Here is an example of implementation in the documentation:

```
Define a map of names to values for JS. Values can be either a MediaQueryList object or a boolean, in which case it’s treated identically to the above, or can be a number or a string, in which case it’s treated like a normal MQ, and can use the normal or range context syntax. Like:

<script>
CSS.customMedia.set('--foo', 5);
</script>
<style>
@media (_foo: 5) { ... }
@media (_foo < 10) { ... }
</style>
```

Documentation Link: https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-5/#custom-mq